# Inserting date from working subselect occurs in error

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Context:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    date DATE
);
```

I have following select query which returns `2000-01-01`, because `LAST_DAY` function returns null because of invalid date.

Edit: I know that `2012-02-31` is incorrect date. That's the point of this question.

```
SELECT IFNULL(LAST_DAY('2012-02-31'), '2000-01-01'); // returns 2000-01-01
```

However when I try to insert this result into the table it returns an error:

> Query Error: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '2012-02-31'

```
INSERT INTO dates (date)
SELECT IFNULL(LAST_DAY('2012-02-31'), '2000-01-01');
```

Why does it happen like that? What's the explanation?

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mdSH8pxVeoJCZ4uMbAypg8/1)

Comment: The code runs fine in MySql 5.5 and 5.6.40 but fails in 5.6.50+

Comment: I tested only 5.7 and 8.0 where it fails.

Comment: February does not have 31 days.  You have a malformed date.

Comment: *However when I try to insert this result into the table it returns an error:* This depends on SQL server mode. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c002dd5b8cce4fc9efa73fa56a1e67ff). Synchronize than check again.

Comment: I'm amazed that somebody suggests that this question should be closed because: *"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"* while there is a fiddle where the issue can be reproduced!

Comment: @forpas I suggested it. Because there is no reason "the author inattentively read the User Manual". A typo seems to be the closest.

Comment: @Akina the question is: why the INSERT statement throws an error but the SELECT statement does not and it is a valid question. Here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89c5615254d0465edd43fe8eb876b111

Comment: @Akina, thanks, this is because of sql mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. I didn't know about this behaviour and still don't know exact explanation. `INSERT` query with IGNORE also works, but this still doesn't explain why it throws error only in one case.

Comment: @forpas *why the INSERT statement throws an error but the SELECT statement does not* `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` does not affect `SELECT` but affect `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Comment: *but this still doesn't explain why it throws error only in one case* The error must occur for error throwing... Removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` removes the source of error. Using INSERT IGNORE converts error to warning. So both factors must present for an error - strict mode and ignoring absence.

Comment: @Akina this should be the answer to the question. What I don't understand is the reason for this question to be closed.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it throws error.  Though it doesn't make sense for me why the implementation of the strict mode affects sub-select. Bypassing strict mode is problematic with more complex query than this. It's also not recommended.

Comment: @forpas the question closing dialogue is a blunt instrument. I think the manual covers this pretty well. If you're 'amazed' by Akina's decision, the British government's decision today to withhold food from poor, hungry (British) children will blow your mind.

Comment: I didn't find the explanation in manual about that issue in user manual...